# How to update the item of the listbox as well as in the iso store local database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, winrt-xaml

As I am working on how to update the data in the local database in windows phone app the problem I am facing is that the item I want to edit is not edited and second item is created in the database due to my code I just want to edit and update the same data item without creating the second item in the database. Please help me how to update the item in the database..

My view model:

```
public void GetPersonalList()
{
   try
   {
      PersonalDataContext AddReminder = new PersonalDataContext(PersonalDataContext.DBConnectionString);
      if (AddReminder.Personal.Count() > 0)
      {
         this.PersonalList.Clear();
         PersonalReminderData reminderdata = new PersonalReminderData();
         List<PersonalTable> personals = reminderdata.GetReminderData();
         foreach (var personalitem in personals)
         {
            this.PersonalList.Add(new PersonalModel
            {
               Id = personalitem.Id,
               Title = personalitem.Title,
               Description = personalitem.Description,
               Date = personalitem.Date,
               Time = personalitem.Time
            });
         }
      }
         else PersonalList.Clear();
   }
   catch
   { }
}

public bool ReminderSaveDetail(PersonalModel personalModel)
{
   bool result = false;
   if (IsEditMode)
   {
      PersonalReminderData personalsaveEditdata = new PersonalReminderData();
      result = personalsaveEditdata.EditPersonalReminder(personalModel);
      IsEditMode = false;
   }
   else
   {
      PersonalReminderData personalsavedata = new PersonalReminderData();
      result = personalsavedata.AddPersonalReminder(personalModel);
   }
   return result;
}

public void ClearData()
{
   this.PersonalModel.Title = string.Empty;
   this.PersonalModel.Description = string.Empty;
   this.PersonalModel.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;
   this.PersonalModel.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
}

public void EditReminder(int id)
{
   if (MessageBoxResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("This will let you edit your reminder,continue?", "Edit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel))
   {
      NavigationService.NavigateToPage(Views.MainPage, EnumForView.MainPage);
      this.PersonalModel = (from personalitem in PersonalList where personalitem.Id == id select personalitem).FirstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

This is my database class:

```
public  bool EditPersonalReminder(PersonalModel personalModel)
{
   try
   {
      using (PersonalDataContext AddReminder = new PersonalDataContext(PersonalDataContext.DBConnectionString))
      {
         PersonalTable reminderDetail = new PersonalTable();

         //var PersonalModel = (from personalitem in AddReminder.Personal where personalitem.Id == personalModel.Id select personalitem).FirstOrDefault();
         reminderDetail.Id = personalModel.Id;
         reminderDetail.Title = personalModel.Title;
         reminderDetail.Description = personalModel.Description;
         reminderDetail.Date = personalModel.Date;
         reminderDetail.Time = personalModel.Time;
         AddReminder.Personal.InsertOnSubmit(reminderDetail);
         AddReminder.SubmitChanges();
         return true;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }        
}

public bool DeletePersonalReminder(int id)
{
   try
   {
      using (PersonalDataContext AddReminder = new PersonalDataContext(PersonalDataContext.DBConnectionString))
      {
         var DeleteDetailObj = (from personalitem in AddReminder.Personal where personalitem.Id == id select personalitem).FirstOrDefault();
         AddReminder.Personal.DeleteOnSubmit(DeleteDetailObj);
         AddReminder.SubmitChanges();
         return true;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}

public List<PersonalTable> GetReminderData()
{
   using (PersonalDataContext AddReminder = new PersonalDataContext(PersonalDataContext.DBConnectionString))
   {
      var reminderData = (from personalitem in AddReminder.Personal orderby personalitem.Id descending select personalitem ).ToList();
      return reminderData;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have this line
AddReminder.Personal.InsertOnSubmit(reminderDetail);
in your EditPersonalReminder method? This will insert new item everytime. What you need is to get the item from DB (for example by ID), make the changes and call SubmitChanges on your DataContext.